# Would an editor for major publisher suggest that a novel have more "diverse" characters?

Tags: editing, publisher

It just seems to me that for some novels -- especially those published in the last ten years or so -- that the author goes out of their way to make a point that a character is Asian, or black, or whatever.  It's almost as if someone, an editor, say, said, "Hey, this is a really good book, but it would be so much better if it was more 'inclusive.'" So the author revises it to make this or that character a racial minority. Does this sort of thing happen nowadays?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a real thing that exists. Do you have any examples?

Comment: You could point to a trend for more diverse characters, and also a contrary trend for authors being criticised for writing characters of other races, sexualities, etc. The question is unanswerable in its current form, although given a specific novel/writer it may be possible to see if anyone has commented in interviews; and in some cases you could look at the race of actual historical figures in based-on-true-story novels. You could ask why JK Rowling latterly decided many of her characters were black and/or gay, although even then I'm not sure you'll get a factual answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Perish the thought:

This is an unverifiable question, and it may get closed for being opinion.

Unfortunately, what happens in those meetings is run through legal and marked confidential. Officially, that would never happen and be discriminatory if it happened. Then again, so would comments about politics and religion. Ultimately, ALL people are people, and capable of discriminatory behavior. Accepting that all people are equal means that all people can be both the hero and the villain. It's all about how the story gets written. Writing is art, and art contains the ugly parts of human existence in equal parts to the beautiful. They can both be beautiful if we accept that being human isn't something to be ashamed of, but something to understand.

It can certainly seem that when you read through book guidelines and every literary agent wants inclusive content, they seem to only want one thing. But it can cut both ways and is hard to prove. At one point, it would have been about not having so many 'colored' people in the story.

I would advise that if your editor asks you to do something different, consider it seriously but don't compromise literary integrity if it's important.

Comment: It's also likely to be very different for someone writing for hire for an existing series of genre novels, where there may be expectations that romance novels sell better with certain types of hero, compared to someone with a Pulitzer or even a famous genre novelist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sometimes the publisher will give You advice...
They do know what sells.

(They think they know.)

But in my books I have characters of all shapes and sizes.

Because I live in a world with all kinds of people.

Some are stereo typical, and some are not.
Just like life.

And then some of my books are with Aliens and Synthetic people...